# How to read large matrix from a csv efficiently in Octave

Tags: performance, octave

There are many reports of slow performance of Octave's `dlmread`. I was hoping that this was fixed in 3.2.4, but when I tried to load a csv file that has a size of ca. 8 * 4 mil (32 mil in total), it also took very, very long time. I searched the web but could not find a workaround for this. Does anybody know a good workaround?

Comment: Do you mean by "size of ca. 8 * 4 mil", that the matrix has 32 million entries or has a dimension 8 million by 4 million?

Comment: @Woltan: 32 million in total. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and had R handy, so my solution was to use "read.csv" in R, and then use the R package "R.matlab" to write a ".mat" file, and then load that in Octave.

"read.csv" can be pretty slow too, but this worked very well in my case.

Comment: What's the ram size of your machine? I have a 10 million entries database and I'd like to know what's better, R, Octave or another program? my pc has 4 gb ram. If I can use R it would be amazing...

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Octave has a bug that adding data to a very large matrix takes more time then adding the same amount of data to a small matrix.

Below is my try. I choose to save data each 50000 lines, so meanwhile I could already take a look instead of being forced to wait. It is slower for small files, but much faster for larger files.

```
function alldata = load_data(filename)
    fid = fopen(filename,'r');
    s=0;
    data=[];
    alldata=[];
    save "temp.mat" alldata;
    if fid == -1
        disp("Couldn't find file mydata");
    else
        while (~feof(fid))
            line = fgetl(fid);
            [t1,t2,t3,t4,d] = sscanf(line,'%i:%i:%i:%i %f', "C"); #reading time as hh:mm:ss:ms and data as float
            s++;
            t = (t1 * 3600000 + t2 * 60000 + t3 * 1000 + t4);
            data = [data; t, d];
            if (mod(s,10000) == 0)
                #disp(s), disp("  "), disp(t), disp("  "), disp(d), disp("\n");
                disp(s);
                fflush(stdout);
            end
            if (mod(s,50000) == 0)
                load "temp.mat";
                alldata=[alldata; data];
                data=[];
                save "temp.mat" alldata;
                disp("data saved");
                fflush(stdout);
            end
        end
        disp(s);
        load "temp.mat";
        alldata=[alldata; data];
        save "temp.mat" alldata;
        disp("data saved");
        fflush(stdout); 
    end
    fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that I am using.

I did not find that sscanf will parse input lines as indicated above.  Also, I didn't use the temp file.

My .csv file has a large number of rows.  They begin with a header of 18 lines and are followed by a data block, each of which has 135 columns.  The following code has been tested.  My file also begins each row with a dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm field.  This will also catch poor lines and indicate where they are by using try/catch.

My .csv file came from a customer who dumped his PARCView load in an Excel file.

```
function [tags,descr,alldata] = fbcsvread(filename)
  fid = fopen(filename,'r');
  s = 0;
  data=[];
  alldata=zeros(1,135);
  if fid==-1
    disp("Couldn't find file %s\n",filename);
  else
    linecount = 1;
    while (~feof(fid))
      line = fgetl(fid);
      data2 = zeros(1,135);
      if linecount == 1
    tags = strsplit(line,",");
      elseif linecount == 2
    descr = strsplit(line,",");
      elseif linecount >= 19
    data = strsplit(line,",");
    datetime = strsplit(char(data(1))," ");
    modyyr = strsplit(char(datetime(1)),"/");
    hrmin = strsplit(char(datetime(2)),":");
    year1 = sscanf(char(modyyr(3)),"%d","C");
    day1 = sscanf(char(modyyr(2)),"%d","C");
    month1 = sscanf(char(modyyr(1)),"%d","C");
    hour1 = sscanf(char(hrmin(1)),"%d","C");
    minute1 = sscanf(char(hrmin(2)),"%d","C");
    realtime = datenum(year1,month1,day1,hour1,minute1);
    data2(1) = realtime;
    for location = 2:134
      try
        data2(location) = sscanf(char(data(location)),"%f","C");
      catch
        printf("Error at %s %s\n",char(datetime(1)),char(datetime(2)) );
        fflush(stdout);
      end_try_catch
    endfor
    alldata(linecount-18,:) = data2;
    if mod(linecount,50) == 0
      printf(".");
      fflush(stdout);
    endif
      endif
      linecount = linecount + 1;
    endwhile
    fclose(fid);
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I should add that in the time it took me to write the code above and execute it, csvread, in another window, which was started two hours prior, had not yet returned.