# Using R to write a .mat file not giving the right output?

Tags: r, csv, octave

I had a .csv file that I wanted to read into Octave (originally tried to use csvread). It was taking too long, so I tried to use R to workaround: [How to read large matrix from a csv efficiently in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552384/how-to-read-large-matrix-from-a-csv-efficiently-in-octave)
This is what I did in R:

```
forest_test=read.csv('forest_test.csv')
library(R.matlab)
writeMat("forest_test.mat", forest_test_data=forest_test)
```

and then I went back to Octave and did this:

```
forest_test = load('forest_test.mat')
```

This is not giving me a matrix, but a struct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `read.csv` doesn't return a matrix; it returns a data.frame. Maybe try  `writeMat("forest_test.mat", forest_test_data=as.matrix(forest_test))`

Comment: I tried both MrFlick and BondedDust's answers and am still getting a struct. Now however it will show the whole matrix...maybe there is a way to pull matrix data out of a struct?

Comment: Have anybody found "writeMat" very slow? It used to be faster when I was using it earlier in a the past few weeks. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your exact question, you are using the `load` function wrong. You must not assign it's output to a variable if you just want the variables on the file to be inserted in the workspace. From Octave's `load` help text:

> If invoked with a single output argument, Octave returns data
>   instead of inserting variables in the symbol table.  If the data
>   file contains only numbers (TAB- or space-delimited columns), a
>   matrix of values is returned.  Otherwise, 'load' returns a
>   structure with members corresponding to the names of the variables
>   in the file.

With examples, following our case:

```
## inserts all variables in the file in the workspace
load ("forest_test.mat");
## each variable in the file becomes a field in the forest_test struct
forest_test = load ("forest_test.mat");
```

But still, the link you posted about Octave being slow with CSV files makes referece to Octave 3.2.4 which is a quite old version. Have you confirmed this is still the case in a recent version (last release was 3.8.2).

Answer (score 1):

There is a function designed to convert dataframes to matrices:

```
?data.matrix

forest_test=data.matrix( read.csv('forest_test.csv') )
library(R.matlab)
writeMat("forest_test.mat", forest_test_data=forest_test)
```