# Error in writeFieldNames while convert data frame into MATLAB mat

Tags: r, dataframe

Refer to the answer in [Using R to write a .mat file not giving the right output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346314/using-r-to-write-a-mat-file-not-giving-the-right-output),
I am trying to convert data frame format data into MATLAB, but these error message is met:

`Error in writeFieldNames(names(structure), maxLength = 32) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3`

The code sample below can reproduce the error:

```
col1 <- c("BW90N01920_01720_01320_00440_00960_00860_01320_00440_0_0")
col2 <- c("S03_M1746")
df <- data.frame(col1, col2) 
library(R.matlab)
writeMat("df.mat", x = df)
```

Does anybody know how to get through this error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with your example. What is your `sessioInfo()`?

Comment: This is the complete version error message `Error in writeFieldNames(names(structure), maxLength = 32) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
In addition: Warning message:
package R.matlab?was built under R version 3.2.1`

Comment: You should upgrade your version of R. Your example works for me with R version `3.2.1` and `R.matlab` version `3.2.0`. After writing the `.mat` file, I am able to read it with Octave version `3.8.2`.

Comment: @Pascal , thanks a lot. Due to a proxy issue, I can't upgrade my R right now, I will try this later.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912268/error-in-r-data-table-v1-9-6-function-fread